# Program that makes Windows 7 look like Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7

I am new here but I am looking for a program that I can use to fool my friends into thinking I am using Windows 8 or at least I hope so.

Ideally I want a program that is.....

- Free (I am not looking to spend anything, not even a few dollars. xD)
- Easy to install/configure.
- Not hard to use.
- Can definitely make Windows 7 look exactly like Windows 8
- Only runs on one account (Don't want it running on the whole computer, just my own user account).
- At the most, probably one that doesn't need administrative permissions, but of course most utilities these days need administrative permissions to run, but it would be nice if you could find one. :)

Any suggestions? I would also like one that almost simulates the new start menu in Windows 8. Got any good suggestions?

**Note:** Just to clarify, I am not looking to *install* Windows 8, but to just make my Windows 7 Laptop *appear* to look like it's running Windows 8.

Is there a program that can help me achieve this?

Comment: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-7-like-8.html has a sequence of steps to make Windows 7 look more like Windows 8, although not the simple install you are looking for.

Comment: http://www.thememypc.com/windows-8-transformation-pack-8-1/ Something like this?

Comment: @mc110- Didn't quite work out for me. Especially the Rainmeter method. I got stuck somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Shub- Didn't work. Everytime I clicked instal it said it could find something.

Comment: 'It could find something' What could it find? Or do you mean 'couldn't', if so, then make sure you run the installer as Admin (Right click > Run as Admin)

Comment: I would thoroughly recommend skinpacks: http://skinpacks.com/download/windows-7/win8-1-skinpack/.  The instructions are easy enough to follow.  I'm not posting this as an answer though because it applies to the *whole* computer (AFAIK) and doesn't have the bootskin like you can opt for in the transformation pack.  I prefer this to transformation packs because they're much easier to remove fully.  If you like this though just let me know and I'll post it as a full answer with more details ;)

Comment: I see a whole RANGE of questions like this coming on. "Program to make [insert OS here] look and feel like [insert different OS here]?" I like this question, but I will get sick of all the other ones that will follow.

Comment: How'd we go with this one, boys?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Rainmeter**

Download Rainmeter 4.0 (r2746) [here](https://github.com/rainmeter/rainmeter/releases/download/v4.0.0.2746/Rainmeter-4.0.exe). Go ahead and install it (It *will* require administrative rights to install, a UAC prompt will appear). Side note: if the user account is not an administrator, use the [run-as command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx) to execute.

**Install the Theme**

Find the theme you want (For help, [here are the search  results](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/customization/skins/themes/?q=windows%208&offset=0) that yield 'Windows 8')

**....or**

Grab [UXThemePatcher](https://skinpacks.com/download/skin-pack-auto-uxthemepatcher/), run the following theme - [Windows X SkinPack](http://myskinpack.com/download-windows-x-skinpack/) (For free) and reboot the device.

Alternate skin (For $9.99) is [SkinPack Collection for Win10/8.1/7](https://skinpacks.com/windows-skinpack-collections-for-win108-17/)